# Canvas element not behaving properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

Im using `html2canvas` to convert a div element to an image.

It's working fine in the fiddle demo, but in the site demo, the text are offset-ted to the right and is not behaving properly when clicking the button to convert to image.

**HTML**

```
<div class='text-area'>
<textarea>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt</textarea>
</div>
<input type='submit' id='submit' value='CONVERT TO IMAGE'>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
$("#submit").click(function() { 
        html2canvas($(".text-area"), {
            onrendered: function(canvas) {
                $('.text-area').html(canvas);
            }
        });

    });
```

**[see fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/wgo6g25f/)**

**[see site demo here](http://relumastudio.com/test/)**

see fiddle and demo links above. both have the same exact code but I don't know where exactly is the problem.

any help is greatly appreciated.

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are missing a `DOCTYPE` declaration at the top of your file on your hosted site. Try adding this to the top of your index file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```